# Using rvest or xml to parse link to a next page?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Working on learning to scrape data from websites. I've been playing around with the rvest package and have got a hold of how to extract nodes with the selector gadget etc. For a quick project I'm looking to extract data from a flight website, turn it into a data frame which I can later subset and have emailed to me with flights that are useful. Anywho the code I'm working with is below.

```
library(rvest)
reg = paste("http://www.secretflying.com/usa-deals/") 

#read the text from the flight deal-----------
fly_deals = read_html(reg)
fly_deals = html_nodes(fly_deals, ".entry-title a")
fly_deals = html_text(fly_deals)
fly_deals = as.data.frame(fly_deals)

#add link (not sure how to access the link)
fly_deals$correpsonding_link = 'corresponding_link'

#last step would filter out for NYC
fly_deals = fly_deals[grepl("NEW YORK", fly_deals$fly_deals),]
```

What I'd like to do now is access the page associated with each row aka each node, this way I can build another column with the corresponding link that can be accessed straight from my email. Hence the final product would look something like this:
[image]

appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
library(rvest)

deals_link <- "http://www.secretflying.com/usa-deals/"
deals_info <- deals_link %>% read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(".entry-title a")

fly_deals <- data.frame(deals = html_text(deals_info), correpsonding_link = html_attr(deals_info,"href"))

fly_deals[grepl("NEW YORK", fly_deals$deals),]
```

Output:

```
 deals                                                                  
 NON-STOP FROM NEW YORK TO CARTAGENA, COLOMBIA FOR ONLY $328 ROUNDTRIP  
 XMAS & NEW YEAR: NEW YORK TO THE TURKS & CAICOS FOR ONLY $231 ROUNDTRIP
 NEW YORK TO BOSTON (& VICE VERSA) FOR ONLY $66 ROUNDTRIP               
 correpsonding_link                                                         
 http://www.secretflying.com/2016/new-york-cartagena-colombia-296-roundtrip/
 http://www.secretflying.com/2016/hot-new-york-turks-caicos-58-one-way/     
 http://www.secretflying.com/2016/new-york-boston-vice-versa-66-roundtrip/
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This was perfect. i see html_attr is the esstential piece missing. Thank you!!